# Raspberry Pi Custom resolution for 1280x320 LCD

Tags: hdmi

I have a Raspberry PI and a 1280x320 pixels ultra wide LCD. Is it possible to have a custom resolution for this to make work correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter in config.txt that can be used for just this purpose:

```
hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
width        width in pixels
height       height in pixels
framerate    framerate in Hz
aspect       aspect ratio 1=4:3, 2=14:9, 3=16:9, 4=5:4, 5=16:10, 6=15:9
margins      0=margins disabled, 1=margins enabled
interlace    0=progressive, 1=interlaced
rb           0=normal, 1=reduced blanking
```

So `nano /boot/config.txt` and append something like:

```
hdmi_cvt 1280 320 60
```

Then reboot and you should have it!

Comment: So just add this line? hdmi_cvt 1280 320 60

Comment: I've done this but it doesn't output anything:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1280 320 60 6 0 0 0

Answer (score -1):

Resolution set to 1920x480 pixels and this resolves the issue I've been having.